# How to transform Maximize[...] to LinearProgramming[...]?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem that looks something like this:

```
Maximize[{1+x+3*y,0<=x<=1 && x+2*y<=4},{x,y}]
```

Now, I want to use Linear Programming to solve this problem, assuming this is more efficient.

Unfortunately, Linear Programming has a different interface, looking something like this:

```
1 - LinearProgramming[{-1, -3}, {{1, 2}}, {{4, -1}}, {{0, 
 1}, {-Infinity, Infinity}}].{-1, -3}
```

By hand, I do the following main steps for this translation:

- Determine constraints and translate this to bounds
- Extract constant offset of objective function (in this case, the offset is 1)
- Translate maximization problem into a minimization problem

Does Mathematica provide support to automate this transformation? In order words, what is the simplest way to do this transformation (automatically)?

---

**A partial solution:**

I think that if I would know how to do the following transitions, I could solve my problem:

```
x+4*y-z      -> {1,4,-1}
x+2*y<=z     -> {1,2,-1}
x+2*y+10<=4  -> -6
```

These transitions correspond to extracting factors before variables and to collecting constants.

Comment: "Translate maximization problem into a minimization problem" -at least this part is easy: maximization of an objective function is the same as minimizing the negation of the same objective function.

Comment: For the coefficients, a modification of `Normal[CoefficientArrays[{x + 4*y - z == 0, x + 2*y == z}, {x, y, z}]]` ought to be useful.

Comment: This does not give the transformed problem, but you could use the internal function ``TryLinearProgramming`` which provides an interface similar to `Minimize`:  ``-Optimization`LinearProgramming`TryLinearProgramming[
   Null, -(1 + x + 3*y), {0 <= x <= 1, x + 2*y <= 4}, {x, y}][[1, 1]]``.

Comment: @Peter I'll write something up in a few hours, although I'm hoping someone will actually write a function that can transform the arguments of Maximize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this unfortunately does not provide one with the actual transformation of the arguments to `Maximize`/`Minimize`, one work-around could be to use the internal function `TryLinearProgramming`. This function handles arguments similar to `Minimize`:

```
Optimization`LinearProgramming`TryLinearProgramming[
  Null, 
  -(1 + x + 3*y), 
  {0 <= x <= 1, x + 2*y <= 4}, 
  {x, y}
]

(*{{-7, {x -> 0, y -> 2}}}*)
```

`TryLinearProgramming` is called from e.g. `` Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPoint ``, see `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPoint] ``, from which we can learn how to use it. Looking in particular at `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`NonlinearInteriorPointCore] ``, we note that `TryLinearProgramming` has (at least) five arguments: `caller` (a symbol to which generated messages are attached), `f` (the function that is optimized), `consin` (the constraints), `varsin` (the variables), and `prec` (the precision of the output, which is an optional argument that defaults to `Infinity`). `` Options[Optimization`LinearProgramming`TryLinearProgramming] `` and `Options[LinearProgramming]` are identical, and some experimentation teaches us that these options can be supplied in a list as an optional sixth argument.

The output of `TryLinearProgramming` is a list `res` whose length should not exceed one (I haven't figured out what kind of input would actually produce longer lists), and `res[[1]]` can be either the solution to the linear program in the same form as produced by `Maximize`/`Minimize`, or a failure reason that is handled by `` Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`checkReasonForFailure ``. Putting everything together, we can write a new function `MinimizeLP` which acts as an interface to `TryLinearProgramming`:

```
MinimizeLP::usage = StringReplace[StringJoin[StringRiffle[StringSplit[Minimize::usage, "\n"][[{3, 5}]], "\n"]], "Minimize" -> "MinimizeLP"];

MinimizeLP::infea = "No solution can be found that satisfies the constraints.";
MinimizeLP::elem = "The constraints, `1`, contain element type constraints that are not supported.";
MinimizeLP::error = "TryLinearProgramming failed.";
MinimizeLP::malf = "The constraints, `1`, are malformed. This may be, for example, because the constraints do not form equalities or inequalities.";
MinimizeLP::nlin = "Either the constraints, `2`, or the objective function, `1`, contain nonlinear terms.";
MinimizeLP::uneq = "The constraints, `1`, contain unequal type constraints that are not supported.";

Options[MinimizeLP] = Options[LinearProgramming];

MinimizeLP[{f_, cons_}, vars_List, dom_: Reals, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {prec = Infinity, res},

  res = Optimization`LinearProgramming`TryLinearProgramming[
    LinearProgramming, f, cons, vars, prec, FilterRules[{opts}, LinearProgramming]
  ];

  If[Length[res] > 1, Message[MinimizeLP::error]; Return[$Failed]];

  res = First[res];

  res = If[

     ListQ[res],

     res,

     Switch[First[res],

       "CouldNotHandleUnequalConstraints",
       Message[MinimizeLP::uneq, cons];
       $Failed,

       "CouldNotHandleElementConstraints",
       Message[MinimizeLP::elem, cons];
       $Failed,

       "MalformedConstraints",
       Message[MinimizeLP::malf, cons];
       $Failed,

       "NotLinear",
       Message[MinimizeLP::nlin, f, cons];
       $Failed,

       "NotReal",
       Message[MinimizeLP::nreal, f, cons];
       $Failed,

       "NoFeasiblePoints",
       Message[MinimizeLP::infea];
       $Failed,

       _,
       Message[MinimizeLP::error];
       $Failed

     ]

   ];

   res /; res =!= $Failed

 ];
```

Additional definitions should be added to copy the behavior of `Minimize` for other argument patterns.

The maximization problem posed in the question can then be solved following the comment by J.M. as follows:

```
MapAt[Minus, MinimizeLP[{-(1 + x + 3*y), 0 <= x <= 1 && x + 2*y <= 4}, {x, y}], 1]

(*{7, {x -> 0, y -> 2}}*)
```

A MaximizeLP function can easily be created by incorporating these two negations in MinimizeLP.

Finally I suppose `TryLinearProgramming` also allows integer linear programming, but I'm not sure how to invoke this. Note that `TryLinearProgramming` is an undocumented function, so the usual caveats apply.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum) instead of [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize), then you can force [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum) to use [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming) with the [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method) option:

```
FindMaximum[{1+x+3*y, 0<=x<=1 && x+2*y<=4}, {x,y}, Method->"LinearProgramming"]
```

> {7., {x -> 0., y -> 2.}}

Comment: Nice! Can this approach be used to obtain arbitrary-precision results like in Maximize and LinearProgramming? (I'm not sure if this is a requirement for the op.)

Comment: @tom, for arbitrary precision, just increase `WorkingPrecision` as needed. For exact... not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately, I am interested in exact results, so I cannot apply this. But it may be useful for others!

Comment: @Peter `Maximize` with `Method -> "LinearProgramming"` gives you exact results